# goRPC newdispatcher imported and not used

Tags: go, rpc, grpc

I'm working with the [valyala goRPC package](https://godoc.org/github.com/valyala/gorpc#example-Server). I'm trying to implement this example:

```
package main

import (
"errors"
"fmt"
"log"
)

type ExampleDispatcherService struct {
state int
}

func (s *ExampleDispatcherService) Get() int { return s.state }

func (s *ExampleDispatcherService) Set(x int) { s.state = x }

func (s *ExampleDispatcherService) GetError42() (int, error) {
    if s.state == 42 {
    return 0, errors.New("error42")
    }
return s.state, nil
}

func (s *ExampleDispatcherService) privateFunc(string) { s.state = 0 }

func main() {
d := NewDispatcher()

service := &ExampleDispatcherService{
    state: 123,
}

// Register exported service functions
d.AddService("MyService", service)

// Start rpc server serving registered service.
addr := "127.0.0.1:7892"
s := NewTCPServer(addr, d.NewHandlerFunc())
if err := s.Start(); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Cannot start rpc server: [%s]", err)
}
defer s.Stop()

// Start rpc client connected to the server.
c := NewTCPClient(addr)
c.Start()
defer c.Stop()

// Create client wrapper for calling service functions.
dc := d.NewServiceClient("MyService", c)

res, err := dc.Call("Get", nil)
fmt.Printf("Get=%+v, %+v\n", res, err)

service.state = 456
res, err = dc.Call("Get", nil)
fmt.Printf("Get=%+v, %+v\n", res, err)

res, err = dc.Call("Set", 78)
fmt.Printf("Set=%+v, %+v, %+v\n", res, err, service.state)

res, err = dc.Call("GetError42", nil)
fmt.Printf("GetError42=%+v, %+v\n", res, err)

service.state = 42
res, err = dc.Call("GetError42", nil)
fmt.Printf("GetError42=%+v, %+v\n", res, err)

}
```

But when I try to build this I got this error:

```
PS C:\Work\goRPC> go build .\prueba1.go
# command-line-arguments
.\prueba1.go:27: undefined: NewDispatcher
.\prueba1.go:38: undefined: NewTCPServer
.\prueba1.go:45: undefined: NewTCPClient
```

I added the package `import "github.com/valyala/gorpc"` but now I get this error:

```
# command-line-arguments
.\prueba1.go:7: imported and not used: "git
.\prueba1.go:29: undefined: NewDispatcher
.\prueba1.go:40: undefined: NewTCPServer
.\prueba1.go:47: undefined: NewTCPClient
```

I know this is a noobie doubt about golang, but I'm clueless about what to do.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to qualify identifiers with import prefix to make them defined

```
d := gorpc.NewDispatcher()
```